# How to Stay as "Logged in" mode in titanium Alloy App when App window closed from background mode?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have made simple login Application in titanium alloy in which user have to login by username and password. I have noticed that after login in to App whenever user operate Application and suddenly he/she close Application from background mode, App automatically goes in Logged Out mode even he/she Did not manually Logged out from Application. How I can make settings in App so that After logged in, It always stays in Home screen titanium alloy window even after closing app from background.

Please suggest your comments in code or useful links

Thank You
Raj

Comment: You can use Ti.App.properties to set a variable to check if user is manually logged out from app or not. Also you can save the credential of the user if needed for further use.

Comment: Hi Suraj, can you please provide information what to set in Ti.App.properties ? I have used Loggedin Boolean type properties in Tiapp.xml Alloy App. But how and where to check if used is logged in ?? can you please provide how to save credential in local App because it will be require for my future use too. If possible can you provide me some lines of code so i can understand.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use share properties: [Titanium.App.Properties](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties)

E.g:

```
if(Ti.App.Properties.getBoolean("userIsLogged", false){
 //redirect home
}else{
 // redirect login
}

//login e.g:
var successLogin=function(e){
Ti.App.Properties.setBoolean("userIsLogged", true);
};
```

Comment: Hi Jagu, Thanks for your quick response..

   As per your provided code and link above, I have tried it in my alloy App But it seems link we must have to save username and password somewhere after user first time logged in to App So that whenever App will be closed from "Mobile Home background mode", It will still able to get notification messages and at that time when user open app it should not redirect to login controller, Instead it should directly open an app with Home window of App. Can You please provide me code if you have tried for your App ? 

Thanks In andvance

Comment: Raj, is the same. I think you should think a little more. In Ti.App.Properties can store your user name and password or token e.g: 

Ti.App.Properties.setString('token', 'yourToken');

or

Ti.App.Properties.setString('userName', 'userName');
Ti.App.Properties.setString('password', 'password');

Comment: Hi Jagu, As per your mentioned code I have used property and its working for me. But logically its not working when I required to get background notification with alert sound. If I have closed App by swipe (remove)it from background, It will not able to get background sound and notification which is running in App But If I don't swipe App from background then its working fine. But it should Also able to fetch sound notification in App after swipe(remove) App from background mode Because Logically App is not still logged out from App

Comment: should we actually use as per below link ?
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Modeling_a_User_Account_and_Authentication

Comment: Also can it possible by below ?
https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/17376/Appcelerator-Authentication-in-a-mobile-app.html

Comment: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.iOS.BackgroundService

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.iOS.BackgroundService

https://archive.appcelerator.com/question/149890/after-killing-the-app-how-to-keep-background-service-running